# Error Connection refused while sending email using nodemailer in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, nodemailer

I am trying to send email from my Nodejs, Express API. But it is showing

```js
message: "connect ECONNREFUSED 74.125.137.109:465"
name: "Error
```

when I am using configuration like

```js
service: 'Gmail'
or 'smtp.gmail.com', or host: 'mail.gmail.com'
port: 465,
  secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // generated ethereal user
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, // generated ethereal password
  }
```

.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can resolve it? TIA